# Debian Install: No network card detected

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, installation

During fresh installation of Debian 11.5 in a Yoga 3 Pro laptop, network card is not detected.
A bunch of models are shown during the process, but clicking on them will cause no effect.
I am trying with the nonfree bd uso
My network card is a Broadcom one (as per Windows OS)
The laptop has no ethernet connection so can't try with cable.
How can I proceed?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773181/lenovo-yoga3-pro-wifi-driver-does-not-work). You need internet for that, so either connect via ethernet or even tether to your phone. You could also try [post1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773181/lenovo-yoga3-pro-wifi-driver-does-not-work) and [post2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723810/no-wireless-ubuntu-15-10-for-lenovo-yoga-3-11).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question appears answered on Ask Ubuntu site.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing Ubuntu instead of Debian,tethering with my phone during install process and it worked.
After install, wifi card is automatically detected.
Thanks